# how to compare two dates using its month and year in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

```
*date1=@"21/07/2016";
date2=@"20/08/2016";
NSComparisonResult result;
result = [date1 compare:date2];*
```

It compares only date and show output **date1** is less
now i want to compare this dates using its month and year also

Comment: Your date1 date2 is nadate or string?

Comment: its a string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your string to date and then compare it will give you proper result.

Try below code.

```
NSString *strTimeIn=@"21/07/2016";
NSString *strTimeOut=@"20/08/2016";

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *dtOne=[format dateFromString:strTimeIn];
NSDate *dtTwo=[format dateFromString:strTimeOut];

NSComparisonResult result;
result = [dtOne compare:dtTwo];
```